# Why variance must divide by population?

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, sampling-theory

According to page 2 of this [paper](http://people.wku.edu/david.neal/382/sampling/Chebyshev.pdf), if $X$ is an arbitrary measurement with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and $\overline{x}$ is the sample mean from random samples of size n, then:

$$\displaystyle\sigma_{\overline{x}}^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}.$$

This is not something obvious, and I wonder if it has a name or is stated formally somewhere.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have  a name but it is an immediate consequence of two facts:

$Var (cY)=c^{2} var (Y)$ if $c$ is a constant.

Variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of the variances.

The variance of $\overline {x}$ is therefore $\frac 1 {n^{2}} {n \, var (X)}=\frac {\sigma^{2}} n$.

Comment: The second fact can be generalized, as we only require the variables are uncorrelated.

Comment: I'm a bit stumped by this fact.  Suppose we magically got a sample with $\sigma_{n}^2 = \sigma^2$ calculated manually.  Wouldn't this formula differ from the calculated result, and is thus incorrect?

Comment: @muxo what you are trying to calculate is the variance of a random variable (the mean when you haven't yet observed any outcomes). If you plug-in your observations you are talking about the sample vaiance

Comment: Oh I see!  $\sigma_{\overline{x}}^2$ is the variance of the mean, not the variance of the measured quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Most detailed and easy to understand explanation I can found is in this [link](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/node/167/):

$\textrm{var}(\bar{X})=\textrm{var}\left(\dfrac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}{n}\right)$

$=\textrm{var}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}X_1+\dfrac{1}{n}X_2+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n}X_n\right)$

$=\dfrac{1}{n^2}\textrm{var}(X_1)+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\textrm{var}(X_2)+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\textrm{var}(X_n)$

$=\dfrac{1}{n^2}[\sigma^2+\sigma^2+\cdots+\sigma^2]$

$=\dfrac{1}{n^2}[n\sigma^2]=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$

Thus:

$$\textrm{var}(\bar{X})=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$$